# How to sort model object fields written in Cyrillic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sorting, icu

I need to sort my model objects. I know that there are two main ways to do this in Django, either by adding `ordering` to the `Meta` class of my model, or using `order_by` in the view. However, when the words are written in the Cyrillic alphabet, the ordering fails.

I've managed to solve this problem for strings by using the `icu` library with the following method:

```
def sort_strings(string, locale=None):
    import icu
    if locale is None:
        return sorted(string)
    collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(locale))
    return sorted(string, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

But this doesn't work when trying to sort model objects. For example, I want to sort my `Song` model by title, so I have for example `Африка`, `Ты знаешь`, and `Хочешь`, which should be ordered in that order, but it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Can you give examples of two words that get sorted in the wrong order with `order_by`?

Comment: Sure, I've edited with an example @alani

Comment: The sort_strings() function is flawed. If the locale value is specified, you are using PyICU, if you do not specify the locale, you are using the default collation in Python. If you are sorting English words, for instance, specifying an English locale will give you a different sort order to not specifying the locale. If i have list  ["a", "Z", "A"], using sorted without key yields ['A', 'Z', 'a'] and using PyICU you get ['a', 'A', 'Z']. Don't mix and match collation algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

The `order_by` in Django already supports correct ordering by Cyrillic characters.

Here is a demonstration with some unsorted records:

```
for object in objects:
    print(object.word)
```

Gives:

```
президент
мне
совершенно
человек
официальный
республики
ужасный
нравится
не
```

Here is the same with `order_by`:

```
for object in objects.order_by('word'):
    print(object.word)
```

Gives:

```
мне
не
нравится
официальный
президент
республики
совершенно
ужасный
человек
```

These words are in correct order according to the Cyrillic alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in your case the sorting is done on the database side so check what collation/locale is set in your database.